# Interseção entre colunas de tabelas distintas no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Seguindo as regras:

**1 - Resuma o problema:**
Não Estou conseguindo realizar uma Interseção entre colunas de tabelas distintas

**2 - Inclua detalhes sobre o seu objetivo**

Estou construindo um BINGO em PHP e preciso realizar uma Interseção entre duas tabelas distintas no meu banco MySQL
a coluna com os numeros sorteados e a coluna com a sequencia inserida nas cartelas.

**3 - Descreva os resultados atuais e os esperados**

 **===== TRECHO EDITADO**

Vamos a um exemplo passo-a-passo do que o INNER JOIN fez e o que eu esperava que ele fizesse:
Primeiro temos que criar duas tabelas (segue estrutura simplificada já com valores inseridos):

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tabela_1`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coluna_a` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


INSERT INTO `tabela_1` (`id`, `coluna_a`) VALUES
(1, '1, 2, 3');

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tabela_2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coluna_b` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `tabela_2` (`id`, `coluna_b`) VALUES
(1, '1, 2, 3'),
(2, '1, 2'),
(3, '1,'),
(4, '2,'),
(5, '1, 2, 3');
```

Nessa estrutura vamos executar o comando:

```
--
-- Comando
-- 
SELECT coluna_a FROM tabela_2
INNER JOIN
tabela_1 ON tabela_2.coluna_b=tabela_1.coluna_a
```

Show de Bola!!! Funciona!!!
Retorna os valores

```
1, 2, 3
```

Agora vamos ao exemplo que não funciona e retorna consulta zero (0)
Primeiro criamos a mesma estrutura, só que agora com valores diferentes:

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tabela_1`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coluna_a` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `tabela_1` (`id`, `coluna_a`) VALUES
(1, '12, 9, 6, 5, 7, 3, 15, 1, 11,');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `tabela_2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coluna_b` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tabela_2`
--

INSERT INTO `tabela_2` (`id`, `coluna_b`) VALUES
(1, '1, 2, 3, 9, 12,'),
(2, '1, 3, 6, 7, 10,'),
(3, '3, 5, 9, 11, 15,'),
(4, '5, 6, 8, 12, 15,'),
(5, '1, 7, 11, 12, 15,');
```

O que eu esperava de retorno, com minha mais profunda humildade e até onde minha inteligência consegue me levar, era o seguinte retorno:

```
3, 5, 9, 11, 15 => id=3
1, 7, 11, 12, 15 => id=5
```

Comment: O INNER JOIN faz exatamente o que você descreveu que deseja, as linhas nas quais os valores são comuns nas duas colunas utilizadas como critério da junção. Não sei o que você quer dizer com "registros dinamicos".

Comment: O INNER JOIN só faz a interseção se a coluna_a tiver o valor igual a coluna_b. Sobre a coluna_a ter valores dinâmicos, quero dizer que o valor da coluna_a esta sempre recebendo novos valores.

Comment: Eu ficaria grato em saber como você faria essa ideia funcionar.  : )

Comment: Quando você executa um comando do banco de dados o resultado deste comando leva em conta a posição do banco de dados no instante da execução. Qualquer posterior modificação do banco de dados só será captada em uma nova execução do comando. O SGBD não advinha o futuro.

Comment: Acho que não me fiz entender. Não é uma bola de cristal que estou precisando, mas cruzamentos de dados inseridos no banco. (1, 5, 7, 8, 10 <=> 2, 5, 10 ==> 5, 10) Simples. Infelizmente o INTERSECT nao funciona no MySQL isso seria muito simples de resolver.

Comment: Mas qual foi o resultado obtido pelo comando SQL que você postou e por qual motivo ele não te atendeu? O INNER JOIN faz exatamente a intersecção.

Comment: Amigo, agradeço imensamente seu esforço em tentar me entender, levando isso em conta, editei minha pergunta com o exemplo pratico e simplificado de como o INNER JOIN funcionou pra mim e o no que ele não me atendeu. Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Existe um erro conceitual na definição de seu banco, seu campos coluna_a e coluna_b não contém vários valores mas sim um único valor, no caso uma única string como por ex.: '1, 3, 6, 7, 10,'. Uma junção é definida como uma operação entre tabelas e o critério entre campos. Minha sugestão é que você normalize as tabelas de seu banco caso os campos coluna_a e coluna_b na realidade devam registrar os diferentes valores, como por exemplo: 1, 3, 6, 7 e 10 um em cada linha.

Comment: Estou entendendo seu raciocínio. A minha questão é que a coluna_b possue numeros de cartelas de um bingo, trata-se da sequencia que possui cada cartela, ou seja, sequencia da letra B = 1, 6, 8, 15, 10. e a coluna_a, são as pedras sorteadas, eu gostaria de saber quando a sequencia da coluna_a, vai aparecer na counas_b, independente da linha ou sequencia,  a coluna_a vai fica recebendo dados, ou seja fica variando.